# How to pass a Node into a class?

Tags: java

I create a Node and want to write a class that if you pass a Node on it, it will return to a String about what contain in the Node

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data.toString();
    }
   

  public String toString(Node head) {
    return head.toString();}
```

My node have the values are 9 8 7 6 but it only return 9. So I add some code in it:

```
public String toString(Node head) {
  String s="";
  Node current = head;
  while (current.toString() != null) {
        s=s+current.toString();
        current=current.next;     }
    return s;
}
```

Then I got error current is null.
I guess error happen on passing Node head into the class, but I have no idea what the error is
Please help me out what did I do wrong in the code?

Comment: calling toString on a null object causes an error try while (current != null)

Comment: Is Node a custom object of yours? If so, what kind of data structure/s does it contain?  Why would you want to call toString() on node if you are trying to access the value of variable of the class? Calling toString() on a null object is bound to create problems too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
while (current.toString() != null) {
```

to

```
while (current != null) {
```

Explanation: I assume `Node head` is a `null` terminated linked list. When you get to the end `current` is set to `null`. You cannot invoke a method (`toString`) on a `null` object.

Answer (score 1):

Error will occur for `while (current.toString() != null) {` when `current==null`.

You need to check for current to be not null to continue the loop.

```java
public String toString(Node head) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // you can stringbuilder here
  Node current = head;
  while (current != null) {
     sb.append(current.toString());
     current=current.next;     
  }
  return s.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to check whether an object is null or not, it can directly be checked with the null keyword.

For Example :

```
1. current == null
2. current != null
```

Both the given cases are syntactically correct. In your case you should go for 2nd option.toString() is not needed to check if the object is null or not.

Assuming that you are trying to concat integers from the given nodes.To concat you can just append the val to string.(i.e using + operator)

```
while (current != null) {   // checks whether current node is not null
        s=s+current.data;  // appending value without toString() method
        current=current.next;     
}
```